# pylab.scatter creates colorbar with weird white lines

Tags: python, macos, pdf, matplotlib

When I run this on OSX Yosemite the colorbar generted has weird white lines (see image below). Is there any way I can generate a colorbar without these ugly lines?

```
import pylab
import numpy
x = numpy.random.random(50)
y = numpy.random.random(50)
s = pylab.scatter(x,y,c=y)
pylab.colorbar(s)
pylab.savefig('/Users/kilojoules/plot.pdf')
```

[image: full graph]

[image: see the lines?]

Comment: Yea, clean your printer head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue (not of matplotlib, but many pdf viewers) which is also described in the documentation of the [colorbar function](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.colorbar) (along with a work-around):

```
# create the colorbar
cbar = pylab.colorbar(s)

# set the color of the lines
cbar.solids.set_edgecolor("face")
```

This should fix it.

For further reading: [the relevant issue on github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1188)